# How to create a user in linux and make a command autoexecute everytime the user opens a shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to create a new user in ubuntu making the user's shell execute a specific command everytime the user logs in, thanks in advance.

Comment: i need a cup of coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a new user on Linux with the `useradd`

You can see all the options by typing `man useradd`

If you want them to have a program run every time put the command in their `.bashrc` file.

If you want this for all new accounts on this machine you can adjust (or create):

```
/etc/default/useradd
  Default values for account creation.
```

Also, if  `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` exists, it is executed after the user account creation, to do any local setup.  The arguments passed to adduser.local are:

```
username uid gid home-directory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the command to be executed for every user add it to /etc/bash.bashrc.local